# check whether given latitude and longitude is in a set of lat/lon in sqlite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

In my iphone app, I have a sqlite table with latitudes and longitudes of USA([All weather stations of USA](http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/stations/index.jsp)) . What is the sqlite query to check whether given latitude and longitude is in a set of lat/lon in sqlite?

I mean I have the lat/lon set of New York as (42.75,73.80),(37,-122) but am searching with a lat/lon which is near New York, like (42.10,73.20)

How to find if this (42.10,73.20) is near New York?

- Answer for mtoepper

Custom Functions in SQLITE (Eg.ACOS)

```
//Include this code in your project
static void ACOSFunc(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv)
{
    assert(argc == 1);
    if (sqlite3_value_type(argv[0]) == SQLITE_NULL) {
        sqlite3_result_null(context);
        return;
    }
    double input = sqlite3_value_double(argv[0]);
    sqlite3_result_double(context, acos(input)  );
}
```

And add this after creating database connection.

```
sqlite3_create_function(db.sqliteHandle, "ACOS", 1, SQLITE_UTF8, NULL, &ACOSFunc, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not used this before but try below query:

SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;

This query is working fine in SQL so just try this.. Hope it will work in SQLite.

Cheers,
Pragnesh

Comment: SELECT *, ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(37) ) * COS( RADIANS( Latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( Longitude ) - RADIANS(-122) ) + SIN( RADIANS(37) ) * SIN( RADIANS( Latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM zipcodes order by distance < 25  LIMIT 0 , 20

Comment: had to done function define functions like ACOS,COS, RADIANS,SIN since they are not available in sqlite.. thanks for this wonderfull sqlite query

Answer (score 2):

For performance, you may want to consider also storing lat/long pairs that represent a bounding box around each real lat/long point, that have the point of interest in the center.

Then you are just doing a simple check to see if the lat/long of interest is inside a box.

After you find a hit you could do a more complex circular calculation to see if it's really "near", instead of that approximation.  The pairs can be calculated to whatever rough distance you consider "near".

Answer (score 1):

Great Pragnesh. Its working very well. It seems you have a good hand on iphone issues.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table looks a bit like this:

```
stations:
id      | name     | lat     | lng
1617760 | Hilo, HI | 19.7303 | -155.0558
```

the query would be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stations WHERE lat=? AND lng=?
```

(where the "?" are parameters)

If there's no match, you will get a 0, else a 1 (assuming you don't have multiple stations at one point ;))

Comment: am sorry..the way i wrote my question is wrong. i have edited that. Thanks  for answering me.

Comment: @Sijo: Aha, now it makes more sense :)